# SQLite - Return Columns Names of Data not Null after With Clauses

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, unpivot, union-all

I'm trying to get the column names from a query. The Column names in my case are battery voltages and not every ID is compatible with every battery voltage so I have 2nd table that maps which ids have which voltage. If it's null then it doens't support that voltage. I would like a final query of voltages for that id. So column names that has data.

I've tried the following in hoped it would return two columns, names and notnull so then I could do one last query on that and filter out the null data and get result battery voltage. But the following returned nothing and no errors.

```
 WITH previous_results AS(SELECT *
      FROM Table1
      JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.table2id = Table2.table2id
), second_results AS( SELECT *
  FROM previous_results
  WHERE previous_results.id= '2'
  )

 SELECT c.name, c.[notnull] FROM pragma_table_info('second_results') c ;
```

This way probably won't work, so can someone help me with a solution? I provided a visual so you can see what I'm looking for in the end. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It *looks like* you want names of columns of `table2` that have non-null values for a given `id`. If so, you can use `union all`:

```
select '12' as colname from table2 where tbl2_id = 2 and col_12 is not null
union all select '24'  from table2 where tbl2_id = 2 and col_24 is not null
union all select '48'  from table2 where tbl2_id = 2 and col_48 is not null
```

I assumed column names `col_12`, `col_24` and `col_48` in `table2`.

If you actually want to filter on `id` from `table1`, then you can `join`, and move the filtering on `id` to the `where` clause of the outer query:

```
select t2.colname
from (
    select tbl2_id, '12' as colname from table2 where col1_12 is not null
    union all select tbl2_id, '24'  from table2 where col1_24 is not null
    union all select tbl2_id, '48'  from table2 where col1_48 is not null
) t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.tbl2_id = t2.tbl2_id
where t1.id = 2
```